# How to convert date into correct format?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using following code to convert user selected date into following date format for saving purpose. But it doesn't convert 2017 year. It get it as 2016.

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $start);
$new_date_in = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($pieces[2]." ".$pieces[1]." ".$pieces[0]));
```

when I echo **$start** , it gives **Wed Mar 08 2017**

but when I echo **$new_date_in**, it gives  **2016-03-09**

2016 dates convert it correctly. please give me a solution.

Comment: Well what do you think is in `$pieces[0]`

Comment: `$new_date_in = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($pieces[2]." ".$pieces[1]." ".$pieces[3]));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $start);
$new_date_in = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($pieces[2]." ".$pieces[1]." ".$pieces[3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong pieces and passing `08 Mar Wed`.  `strtotime()` is pretty good.  Just use `$start`:

```
$new_date_in = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start));
```